# Returning only the first node when parsing XML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I would like my jQuery script to only return ONLY the top node it finds instead of iterating through all the nodes. What do I change in my jQuery script to accomplish that? I know it has to do with the `each(function) {}` but i don't know exactly what should change. Thanks in advance!

jQuery Code:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'xml/timeline.xml',
dataType: 'xml',
success: function(data) {
    $(data).find('channel item').each(function() {
        var fbFeedWrapper = $('<div/>').addClass('fb-feed-wrapper');
        var fbFeedItem = $('<div />').addClass('fb-feed-item');
        $('.socialmedia-list#simlearn').append(fbFeedWrapper);
        fbFeedWrapper.append(fbFeedItem);

        var url = $(this).find('link').text();
        var title = $(this).find('title').text();           
        fbFeedItem.append($('<h1/>').html("<a href='" + url + "'>" + title + "</a>"));                
        var fbItemIcon = $('<div />').addClass('fb-item-icon');
        fbFeedItem.append(fbItemIcon);
        var description = $(this).find('description').text();
                        if (description.length > 80) {
                            description = description.substr(0, 80) + "...";
                        }
        fbFeedItem.append($('<div/>').addClass('fb-item-details').html(description));                            

    })
}


});
```

XML File format:

```
<channel>
<item> // <-- If i Only want the top <item> node returned what should i do?
    <title></title>
    <link></link>
    <description></description>
</item>
<item>
    <title></title>
    <link></link>
    <description></description>
</item>
<item>
    <title></title>
    <link></link>
    <description></description>
</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `.each();` simply find the first of the matched elements. Assign a variable with this object and then change of the `this` references from inside the `.each()` to be the name of the variable.

Example (In the example I name the variable `self`) :

Change the line :

```
$(data).find('channel item').each(function() {
```

to be :

```
var self = $(data).find('channel item').first();
```

Then change all of the occurrences of `this` to be `self`. Also remove the ending brace and bracket of the `.each` function (`})`)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'xml/timeline.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (data) {
        var self = $(data).find('channel item').first();
        var fbFeedWrapper = $('<div/>').addClass('fb-feed-wrapper');
        var fbFeedItem = $('<div />').addClass('fb-feed-item');
        $('.socialmedia-list#simlearn').append(fbFeedWrapper);
        fbFeedWrapper.append(fbFeedItem);

        var url = $(self).find('link').text();
        var title = $(self).find('title').text();
        fbFeedItem.append($('<h1/>').html("<a href='" + url + "'>" + title + "</a>"));
        var fbItemIcon = $('<div />').addClass('fb-item-icon');
        fbFeedItem.append(fbItemIcon);
        var description = $(self).find('description').text();
        if (description.length > 80) {
            description = description.substr(0, 80) + "...";
        }
        fbFeedItem.append($('<div/>').addClass('fb-item-details').html(description));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(data).find('channel item[0]')
    //--------------------^^^-----add [0] to this
```

or with `:first`:

```
$(data).find('channel item:first')
```

or with `:eq()`:

```
$(data).find('channel item:eq(0)')
```

---

Even you can try this:

```
$(data).find('item:eq(0)')
```

Comment: When I tried replacing `$(data).find('channel item').each(function() {` with `$(data).find('channel item[1]')` the jquery won't execute

Comment: `$(data).find('channel item:eq(0)')` worked for me, but 
`$(data).find('channel item[0]')` did not work for me